# Validate XML root tag in the request

Tags: java, xml, jackson

I need to do strict validation of the xml root tag (REQUEST) for the below xml request. I want to do it using JacksonXml. This is a REST API using Springboot. I am using @RequestBody which does the serialization from xml to java object. 
    I tried to find online but didn't come across any solution.

```
    **<REQUEST>
            <FIrSt_name>Sam</FIrSt_name>
            <last_name>Anderson</last_name>
    </REQUEST>**
```

So if the Root tag is something other than REQUEST , this should be treated as invalid request.

Comment: Since you don't want to do a complete XML/XSD validation and just the root tag, you can use XPATH. Extract the root element using XPath and check if it is "REQUEST".

Comment: Thanks Nishit. I edited my question. Can you take a look and let me know? Thanks a lot for the reply